# Refresh platform data in tables after action

Tags: javascript, palantir-foundry, slate, foundry-slate

if i did some edits on data via functions on objects in tables are still the old data.
Only after Browser refresh the changes are visible.
Data is coming via Slate JavaScript Functions from Platform.

Is there a way to refresh this data shown in widget table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Object Set integration in the Slate Platform tab is backed by the Object Set Service search endpoint. This endpoint in turn hits the underlying *index* in the Phonograph data store associated with the object type.

When you make a data change via an Action, there is a brief (normally less than 3s) delay before the changes are reflected in the index. They're *immediately* reflected if you access the modified object(s) by primary key.

So in Slate you can set up an Event "chain" based on the success event broadcast from the Action, through a Toast Widget with a 3-4s timer, to an event that triggers on `w_toastWidget.didClose` -> `s_myObjectSet.run`.

This should tell Slate to update the object set 4 seconds after the successful submission of the Action.

A future planned update to the Object storage infrastructure will provide a version of Actions that guarantees when the request returns successfully that the changes will already be reflected in search results.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. I did after the action_abc.success